# How to use google identity toolkit without importing users

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-identity-toolkit

Is there is any workaround for google identity toolkit where without importing users from identity server still we can use that using google identity toolkit.
Here is the example what we are trying to do :

Let say there is Identity provider Entity (Idp) and another Entity that is Service provider server (SP),Idp do not allow any one to export there users due to security but can set some trust with service provider so that you can allow login using there credentials without exposing there users on any other system.

So that is best workaround using Google Identity toolkit that can allow me to use it without importing any users in Google Identity toolkit but still we can login with any party we want with bare minimum configuration.

Basically we want federation without exporting users from any system but still want to connect with them using some trust agreement between parties so that we can provide them service using the existing user profiles any one having either on some system or enterprise or any of those who are our partners.

Does Any of google tools or technology gives one channel that we can use for the above user case or any work around if there is use google identity toolkit by avoid exporting or registering user on 2 different systems.

I hope there is so many trying or having same use case for there project can answer me or google people can approach this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use Google Identity Toolkit, you do not need to import your users into Google Identity Toolkit. The Identity Toolkit will automatically create a user account for federated login users.

There is one caveat though in this case. Google Identity Toolkit will not know the user's identifier in your system, and the authentication result (i.e. Google Identity Toolkit IdToken) will contains a newly generated user_id along with email, name and photo url etc.

Comment: Yea actually that limitation is only the one we have concern even we not export it manually or automatic but even when once user use it on google tool kit user info will be shared that our clients don't want, We have needs where we need info connecting with there server but not saving any data on the process, So is there is any way or there is any google tool to achieve that ?

Comment: No, Google Identity Toolkit does NOT share user info with any other services. The user info belongs to you developer only.